# How to implement the google translate for particular words from Database in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, api, google-translate, zend-translate

Can I Know how to implement the google translate for particular words in Reactjs ?

Comment: This link explains how to ask a good questions, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .  Search, and research
...and keep track of what you find. Even if you don't find a useful answer elsewhere on the site, including links to related questions that haven't helped can help others in understanding how your question is different from the rest.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **i18n** for language change. But not for particular words.

Comment: How to translate a Particular Word (Translate)  from Database in Reactjs UI ?